# libgpg-error.so.0: no version information available

Tags: systemd

I just started using ubuntu.

every time I want to start|stop|restart a service I get this error:

```
systemctl: /usr/local/lib/libgpg-error.so.0: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20)
```

I did google but I could not find anything helps me.

I realized the problem after I did some changes to `apache2` config file and needed to restart the service.

```
$ apt-cache policy libgpg-error0
libgpg-error0:
  Installed: 1.17-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.17-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.17-3ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ apt-cache policy libgcrypt20
libgcrypt20:
  Installed: 1.6.2-4ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.6.2-4ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1.6.2-4ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libgpg-error0` and `apt-cache policy libgcrypt20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you have an additional library in `/usr/local/lib/`:

```
/usr/local/lib/libgpg-error.so.0
```

Clarify why you have installed this library. Then you have two options:

1. Remove the library (backup)

   and your system takes the version in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libgpg-error.so.0 /usr/local/lib/libgpg-error.so.0.bak
   ```
2. Remove the library and create a symbolic link

   if you need the library in `/usr/local/lib/`

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libgpg-error.so.0 /usr/local/lib/libgpg-error.so.0.bak
   sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 /usr/local/lib/
   ```

Comment: Too bad OP never said where it came from...